# I need to make regular working Queue when its not empty in Django

Tags: python, django

**PROJECT**: I am making a web app, where users send a ZIP file, and it saves to the folder. There is a VM continuously looking for that folder where the zip gets extracted. Note that VM is only 1. So I have to extract, sleep for 20 seconds and remove the files from that folder, VM generates the results, then my Django app generates a CSV from those files, and returns it to the user as downloadable. This is the flow.

Problem: **MultiUsers**: I am using a file, like below

```py
    def Uploader(request):
        file=takenFromPost() # let's assume this works.
        with open('busy.txt', 'r') as f:
            if "false" in f:
                with open('busy.csv', 'w') as f:
                    f.write('true') #here I made it true so that if its true, the request doesn't disturb it as single VM
                    f.close()
                finalcsv=workFurther() #here is the whole process lets say.
                with open('busy.csv', 'w') as f:
                    f.write('false')
                    f.close()
                    return render(request, 'worked.html', {'finalcsv':finalcsv})
            elif "true" in f:
                Uploader(request) #here I send this request again to this so that the user keeps waiting and when the
                #files get generated for the second user, he gets the response.
```

Here is the example logic, same as my code works.

**Problem**: Logic seemed me well but the browser doesn't wait much and probably gets timeout maybe but drops the request after certain time. I printed every step with numbering, the 2nd request processes till waiting but gets dropped in the middle but works perfectly for user 1. because the code sleeps for 50 seconds at least during processes for VM.

**Solution which I thought**: What if we save this file in a **Queue** folder and append it to the list, the scanner focuses on **Queue[0]** and then pops **Queue[0]** and deletes the file (zip file) from folder. In this way, the code shall keep executing and producing user_email.csv and then using Ajax on the user side, we can keep request after 10 requests to look for `f"{request.session['email']}.csv"` file somehow.

Problem is when first request returns the response as request render HTML page, how would I make it go to the next process because it will return and wait to be called by the next coming request even if I request the way above, the reason it doesn't work.

It's a Django application, do you have any solution which is not so complex, do I need to make a new python file to keep running parallel to the server? which reads the queue written in the file, picks up the file, processes, and puts the CSV. then Ajax requests and application validates the file if present and then responds accordingly and then Django app only saves the files and adds to the queue, and the external script modifies the script, the `Busy.txt` file. Best if the answer is easy solution because I am stuck at this and need to get out of this by today.
Thanks in ADVANCE. "Together we hit harder."

Comment: Why don't you use two different paths for it and a database? one for checking if it is `true` and the second for writing `true` or `false`. I would suggest opting for a database than writing into files. and If you still want to use the file, then a unique name for the file would be better (such as user_id). another thing that concerns you about timeout, I suggest using`celery`

Comment: @IjazUrRahim actually the 2nd user request initially works fine because it gets into the loop, as when the 1st process is working, `busy.txt` is `True`, and when finished, it becomes `False`. User 2 `request` keeps looping until `busy.txt` becomes `False`